# Visual Studio Event Binding 2012 Web Express

Tags: c#, intellisense, visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2010 I am used to my manual event binding via intellisense looking like the below, with the `new EventHander` wrapper around all my event names.

```cs
public partial class NiftyUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public NiftyUserControl()
    {
        //Bind usercontrol 'page' events
        this.Init += new EventHandler(NiftyUserControl_Init);
    }

    void NiftyUserControl_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Bind usercontrol children events
        cmdBestButtonEver.Command += new CommandEventHandler(cmdBestButtonEver_Click);
    }

    void cmdBestButtonEver_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        //Perform Best Magic Ever
    }
}
```

I installed the new Visual Studio 2012 Web Express and now my event creation process ends up looking like this:

```
public partial class GreatSadness : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public GreatSadness()
    {
        //Bind usercontrol 'page' events
        this.Init += GreatSadness_Init;
    }

    void GreatSadness_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Bind usercontrol children events
        cmdVerySadButton.Command += cmdVerySadButton_Command;
    }

    void cmdVerySadButton_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        // =(
    }
}
```

This is having a negative impact on my ch'i.
How do I tell Visual Studio 2012 to create event bindings that look like the topmost example?

Comment: Why on earth would you want unnecessary delegate instantiations all over the place? This welcome change is seven years overdue.

Comment: Tradition mostly. I didn't realize these were actually two different ways to do things, are they? I was thinking they were the same 'under the hood'.

Comment: They compile to the same IL, but the old way looks uglier.